# Why does my project have both a package-lock.json and yarn.lock file?

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am working on a React project.

I have only used `npm` within the project. I am not sure how the yarn.lock file was generated initially. Is it okay to delete `yarn.lock` since I am not using `yarn`?

When I run `npm install <package>` to install packages, `yarn.lock` is updated but `package-lock.json` remains unchanged, why is that?

Do I need both a `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Did you ever alias `npm` to yarn or something? Is multiple people working on this project?

Comment: I'm the only one working on the project. I dont know how to alias `npm` so I assume not.

Comment: When you write on your terminal just **$ npm** do you see **Usage: npm <command>** ? If you see this, there is no alias for npm.

Comment: The output in my terminal is `Usage: npm <command>` so there is no alias. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, when you use npm, you will see a `package.json` and a `package-lock.json` files.

When you use yarn, you will see a `package.json` and a `yarn.lock` files.

I suggest to push your functional project to git first, then clone the project to a new repository with the same content and do some tests:

1. delete `node_modules`, `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json`
2. `npm install`

You shouldn't see a `yarn.lock` anymore.

Comment: A `yarn.lock` file was not created. I only have a `package-lock.json` now and everything appears to be working fine in my dev environment. Thanks